# Limit input to only accept parentheses, not letters or numbers

Tags: javascript, html

It should only accept parentheses inside the input. It should not accept letters or numbers

```js
function brackets() {
  var inp = document.getElementById("input").value;
  var result = document.getElementById("strong").value;
console.log(inp,result)
  var l = 0;
  var r = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < inp.length; i++) {
    if (inp[i] === "(") {
      l++;
    } else if (inp[i] === ")") {
      r++;
    }
  }
  console.log(l,r)
  if (l == r) {
    document.getElementById("strong").innerHTML = "Matched";
  } else if (l !== r) {
    document.getElementById("strong").innerHTML = "Not matched";
  }

}
document.getElementById("input").addEventListener("input",brackets);
```

```html
<input type="text" id="input" />
<span id="strong"></span>
```

Comment: What do you want exactly? An event listener on input or what?

Comment: I made you a snippet. Please edit it to make a [mcve]

Comment: You cannot use value on container tags and you cannot use innerHTML on input fields

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do it by checking if the character typed is a parenthesis, and if not, slice the last character.

[`slice()` Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice)

```js
function brackets() {
  var inp = document.getElementById("input");

  if (inp.value.slice(-1) != '(' && inp.value.slice(-1) != ')') {
    inp.value = inp.value.slice(0, -1);
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="text" oninput="brackets()" id="input"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

**Explanation :** I have used `keydown` event handler. Whenever the key is pressed, it checks if it's a *paranthesis* or not. I case it's not, the input does not gets entered inside the `input` element.

Doing this will avoid input of character, checking if it's not a parenthesis, and removing it if it's not:

```js
document.getElementById("input").addEventListener("keydown", function(event) {
  if (!(event.shiftKey && (event.key == ")" || event.key == "("))) {
    event.preventDefault();
  }
});
```

```html
<input type="text" id="input" />
```

Comment: @barhatsor read the question again. It should not accept any character except PARANTHESIS :)

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is add onchange event listener to the input. Then when a user types on the input, you can validate the input to be either "(" or ")" otherwise you clear the input box

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
let inp = document.getElementById('input');
var result = "";

inp.addEventListener('keyup', (e) => {

    if(inp.value[inp.value.length - 1] === '(' || inp.value[inp.value.length - 1] === ')'){
        result += inp.value[inp.value.length - 1]           
    }
    console.log(result)
    return result
    
})
```

```html
<input id="input">
```

Answer (score 0):

First, I suggest using regexp and the pattern attribute. https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_pattern.asp

```css
input:invalid {
  border: red solid 3px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>

<p>An input that CANNOT contain parenthesis</p>

<input type="search" id="search" name="search" pattern="[^()]+" title="Invalid input">


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use ASCII codes, which are valid for all languages:

```js
   

$('#parantezMask').on('keypress', function (e) {
    if (!(e.which == 40 || e.which == 41)) e.preventDefault();
});
```

```html
<input type="text" id="parantezMask" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```